# Including null values when using COUNT with a conditional

Tags: sql, count, null

I'm trying to retrieve data from a series of wildlife surveys. For the purpose of this question, I have two primary tables I'm using. One describes "Events" which includes the date and time a survey event took place. The other describes "Observations" which shows each species seen and which survey event the observation took place.

I want is to retrieve a count of a given species during each survey event through a range of dates. I am able to accomplish this on days when that species is seen, but I also want to include entries with a 0 count for events when that species is not observed.

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/4955425)

Comment: Could you post your data structure? What have you tried? What was the result?

Comment: which rdbms? oracle, sql-server, mysql? include some table structures and example data and desired result.  For example @Nikki9696 says use left join which is great but to get to 0 for non observed species you will probably have to generate some kind of cross between the dates and the species to use in your joins

Answer (score 0):

You can select events matching the date range and use a correlated subquery to count observations:

```
select 
  event_id,
  (
    select count(*)
    from observation o
    where o.event_id = e.event_id
    and o.species_id = :species_id
  ) as observation_count
from event e
where event_date between :start_date and :end_date;
```

The real query will differ depending on your DBMS, your table and column names, your data (e.g. is it one observation record per animal or does an observation record contain the number of animals seen?), etc. You would probably have got a better answer had you given more information :-)